# Powering Arduino with reverse car lights?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'd like to build a reverse car sensor using Arduino

When we select reverse gear, the reverse lights powers, so we can take electricity from them.

My question is can i power my Arduino directly from the reverse lights wires, or should i use regulators or anything else?

Comment: What board are you using? Most boards already have a regulator on it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a switching regulator such as the LM2596. You can get a ready board from eBay for about US$1

[image]

Comment: can i use car phone charger as a regulator?

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on the car and your Arduino. There are two factors to consider:

1. Leeching power off lights can have an adverse effect on the car's ability to sense a blown bulb.
2. Many Arduinos have a 2 second delay while the bootloader executes (some even have 8 seconds).

If your car doesn't sense blown bulbs (most modern ones now do, even cheap ones) and you can work without a bootloader (programming directly with a USBasp for example) to avoid the power-on delay, then it may be possible, yes.

As has been mentioned by others, using a switching regulator is the best method for powering the board as it avoids excess power loss through heat (which can especially be a problem in confined spaces). I would recommend not using one of the cheap eBay modules, but instead using a proper "cigarette lighter" to USB adaptor (available from all good gas stations priced $5) which is designed to work with automotive voltages. A car's 12V power has transients in excess of 50V sometimes (back EMF from the spark generation) and the electronics have to be able to cope with that - those cheap eBay modules aren't designed for that and could die taking your Arduino with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to top off the other answers. If you have a fairly modern car that runs on LED lights, you can easily use that voltage. ***MOST*** LEDs run from around 3-6V soyou might want to measure the voltage. If everything is good, then you can connect the positive of the LED to the 5V of your Arduino and GND to GND.